Error message on blue background form?
I am trying to make an error message that is visible and matches the styling of a blue form, image attached. I am having difficulty since the red doesn't stand out against the blue background. Any suggestions?



I know tons of examples where in-line validation errors have their own design treatment and background. That's probably your easiest solution here. I've attached an example below. Some other options would be:

Use a red error icon and a more visible text colour
Outline the text field in red and use a more visible text colour



Good suggestions thanks a lot!
